# Getting ReceiveResponseXML error while sync my data to Quick Books using webconnector

Tags: quickbooks, qbwc

i am using webconnector to sync my data to quick book desktop. i am getting the following error.

> ```
> > QBWC1042: ReceiveResponseXML failed Error message:
> > System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
> > process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
> > not set to an instance of an object.    at
> > QuickBooksItemOps.extractItemQueryResponses(String response, Session
> > sess) in
> > c:\inetpub\wwwroot\QWCInvoiceSample\service\App_Code\QuickBooksItemOps.cs:line
> > 39    at SampleController.processLastAction(Session sess, String
> > response) in
> > c:\inetpub\wwwroot\QWCInvoiceSample\service\App_Code\SampleController.cs:line
> > 188    at QWCInvoiceSample.receiveResponseXML(String ticket, String
> > response, String hresult, String message) in
> > c:\inetpub\wwwroot\QWCInvoiceSample\service\App_Code\QWCInvoiceSample.cs:line
> > 290    --- End of inner exception stack trace --- More info:
> > StackTrace =    at
> > System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
> > message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
> > asyncCall)    at
> > System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
> > methodName, Object[] parameters)    at
> > QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebServiceDoc.receiveResponseXML(String
> > ticket, String response, String hresult, String message)    at
> > QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebService.receiveResponseXML(String
> > ticket, String response, String hresult, String message)    at
> > QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.receiveResponseXML(String wcTicket,
> > String response, String hresult, String message)    at
> > QBWebConnector.WebService.do_receiveResponseXML(String wcTicket,
> > String response, String hresult, String message, Boolean& success,
> > Boolean& timeout) Source = System.Web.Services
> ```

can you guide me to over come the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your C# code is throwing an error. Fix your code.

```
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
> process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
> not set to an instance of an object.    at
> QuickBooksItemOps.extractItemQueryResponses(String response, Session
> sess) in
> c:\inetpub\wwwroot\QWCInvoiceSample\service\App_Code\QuickBooksItemOps.cs:line
> 39    at SampleController.processLastAction(Session sess, String
> response) in
> c:\inetpub\wwwroot\QWCInvoiceSample\service\App_Code\SampleController.cs:line
> 188
```

Or at least post your code up, along with the qbXML response you're parsing, so that we can help you troubleshoot it.